# Draw and save three random values ​to the array from other tables

Tags: java

I try to draw random values ​​from three tables and save them to another table. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, or whether it's correct thinking at all

```
String[] name = {"Audi 100", "Audi 200", "Audi 4000", 
                 "Audi 50", "Audi e-tron",
                 "Audi A2", "Audi A3", "Audi A4", 
                 "Audi A5", "Audi A6", "Audi F103",
                 "Audi 5000", "Audi 80", "Audi 90", 
                 "Audi A1", "Audi A7", "Audi A8",
                 "Audi Allroad", "Audi Cabriolet", 
                 "Audi Coupe", "Audi Coupe S"};

    int[] engine = {10*20};
    int[] numberOfSeats = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Random r = new Random();
    MotorVehicle[] model = new MotorVehicle[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < model.length; i++) model[i] = new
    MotorVehicle((int)(Math.random()*5)+1,name[r.nextInt(name.length)],new 
    Silnik((int)((Math.random()* 250)+50),(long) 
    ((Math.random()*6000l)+50l)));
```

Comment: So what do you expect and how it actually ended up?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help if you don't take the time to share at least what the **MotorVehicle** class constructor is comprised of and what class member variables are used. Also, what in the world is the **Silnik** class?

Comment: @DevilsHnd seems like an Engine in Polish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since we don't what MotorVehicle and Silnik class does, I'm assuming some required data memebers to test your program.
Another thing is - we dont get the purpose of engine[] and numberOfSeats[] array.

discarding those thing, Your program looks fine and doesn't throw any bound exception.

```
class MotorVehicle{
  int motor_a;
  String motor_b;
  Silnik motor_c;
  public MotorVehicle(int i, String string, Silnik silnik) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    motor_a = i;
    motor_b = string;
    motor_c = silnik;
  }

}
class Silnik{
  int silinik_a;
  long silinik_b;
  public Silnik(int i, long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    silinik_a = i;
    silinik_b = l;
  }
}

public class Test extends Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] name = { "Audi 100", "Audi 200", "Audi 4000", "Audi 50", "Audi e-tron", "Audi A2", "Audi A3", "Audi A4",
        "Audi A5", "Audi A6", "Audi F103", "Audi 5000", "Audi 80", "Audi 90", "Audi A1", "Audi A7", "Audi A8",
        "Audi Allroad", "Audi Cabriolet", "Audi Coupe", "Audi Coupe S" };

    int[] engine = { 10 * 20 };
    int[] numberOfSeats = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Random r = new Random();
    MotorVehicle[] model = new MotorVehicle[100];


    for (int i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
      int rand5 = (int)(Math.random()*5) + 1;
      int randN = r.nextInt(name.length);
      String randName = name[randN];
      int rand250 = (int)(Math.random()*250)+50;
      long rand6000 = (long)(Math.random()*6000l)+501;
      model[i] = new MotorVehicle(rand5, randName,new Silnik(rand250, rand6000));
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<model.length;i++) {
      System.out.println(model[i].motor_a + " #  "+model[i].motor_b + " # "+model[i].motor_c.silinik_a + " # "+ model[i].motor_c.silinik_b );
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
1 #  Audi 200 # 123 # 3160
3 #  Audi A4 # 276 # 2625
2 #  Audi e-tron # 267 # 6153
1 #  Audi 100 # 100 # 741
3 #  Audi 4000 # 146 # 6335
3 #  Audi 200 # 174 # 1155
5 #  Audi Allroad # 164 # 5588
4 #  Audi 90 # 250 # 2021
2 #  Audi e-tron # 285 # 4536
5 #  Audi F103 # 92 # 5828
4 #  Audi A7 # 238 # 1049
3 #  Audi A6 # 271 # 2187
1 #  Audi Coupe # 105 # 1422
2 #  Audi A3 # 274 # 4337
3 #  Audi A4 # 211 # 2850
4 #  Audi A4 # 229 # 1048
3 #  Audi 4000 # 238 # 4981
3 #  Audi A8 # 208 # 2051
5 #  Audi 100 # 89 # 5998
4 #  Audi 200 # 77 # 5026
3 #  Audi A7 # 230 # 967
1 #  Audi A4 # 78 # 3321
5 #  Audi 4000 # 243 # 1612
1 #  Audi A7 # 85 # 5704
1 #  Audi A7 # 269 # 1914
5 #  Audi Coupe S # 136 # 6371
4 #  Audi A2 # 224 # 1079
1 #  Audi 4000 # 198 # 2126
5 #  Audi e-tron # 212 # 5673
2 #  Audi 50 # 134 # 3746
1 #  Audi A2 # 150 # 5832
1 #  Audi A5 # 247 # 2257
4 #  Audi Allroad # 180 # 6049
4 #  Audi e-tron # 222 # 3857
3 #  Audi F103 # 170 # 2547
1 #  Audi F103 # 165 # 2669
3 #  Audi 4000 # 266 # 4824
2 #  Audi 200 # 286 # 2328
5 #  Audi 50 # 145 # 5524
4 #  Audi 80 # 243 # 3674
2 #  Audi 90 # 250 # 5193
5 #  Audi A3 # 96 # 524
3 #  Audi A4 # 159 # 1081
2 #  Audi Allroad # 90 # 1882
3 #  Audi F103 # 62 # 5466
3 #  Audi Cabriolet # 148 # 4968
5 #  Audi 5000 # 161 # 2834
2 #  Audi Cabriolet # 242 # 3434
1 #  Audi e-tron # 138 # 4758
3 #  Audi 50 # 171 # 3119
3 #  Audi 90 # 287 # 5967
1 #  Audi 50 # 203 # 5071
5 #  Audi A7 # 171 # 3352
4 #  Audi 80 # 143 # 6441
2 #  Audi Allroad # 166 # 4768
1 #  Audi 5000 # 132 # 4580
3 #  Audi Cabriolet # 260 # 1412
2 #  Audi Coupe S # 253 # 2618
5 #  Audi A4 # 60 # 1015
3 #  Audi 80 # 149 # 1188
1 #  Audi 200 # 78 # 4793
5 #  Audi 200 # 213 # 1298
1 #  Audi e-tron # 213 # 5143
4 #  Audi A2 # 104 # 2000
2 #  Audi 50 # 227 # 5827
3 #  Audi Cabriolet # 139 # 1833
5 #  Audi 80 # 169 # 3545
4 #  Audi Coupe S # 63 # 4705
1 #  Audi A3 # 144 # 6161
3 #  Audi Coupe S # 103 # 1136
2 #  Audi A4 # 103 # 3810
5 #  Audi 200 # 59 # 1457
3 #  Audi 50 # 238 # 3969
3 #  Audi F103 # 148 # 2981
3 #  Audi Allroad # 160 # 5260
4 #  Audi A2 # 264 # 4053
2 #  Audi Coupe S # 179 # 1198
2 #  Audi 5000 # 199 # 4832
1 #  Audi Cabriolet # 126 # 4746
1 #  Audi 50 # 177 # 4372
5 #  Audi A8 # 152 # 5861
5 #  Audi A8 # 77 # 4636
5 #  Audi 90 # 242 # 1312
4 #  Audi Coupe S # 199 # 4370
3 #  Audi 80 # 140 # 3855
4 #  Audi A5 # 189 # 1913
2 #  Audi A8 # 125 # 2068
4 #  Audi 80 # 104 # 2864
3 #  Audi 200 # 263 # 2287
1 #  Audi Allroad # 160 # 4913
3 #  Audi A1 # 254 # 3408
5 #  Audi A6 # 99 # 5840
5 #  Audi 100 # 252 # 3840
3 #  Audi 90 # 165 # 665
1 #  Audi A5 # 214 # 544
5 #  Audi Coupe # 212 # 1058
5 #  Audi 50 # 112 # 5366
3 #  Audi Allroad # 158 # 3290
5 #  Audi 80 # 166 # 6249
4 #  Audi A4 # 121 # 6349
```